# Cannot import SQL file when the database name contains an underscore

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to import an SQL file into a MySQL database using the following command;

```
mysql --user example -p --database example_database < example.sql
```

This returns the error:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 22: Access denied for user 'example'@'%' to database 'example'
```

Notice the database name has trimmed everything after the underscore. The connection details are definitely correct as I can connect to MySql using the following command:

```
mysql --user example -p --database example_database
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely explanation for the observed behavior is that the `example.sql` file contains a statement:

```
  USE example;
```

The error is thrown when that statement is being executed because user `'example'@'%'` is not granted privileges on that database.

(I don't believe the `--database` option value is being trimmed right before an underscore character. The conjecture about the underscore in the database name is a red herring.)

Comment: Yeah that was it. I exported the SQL using `mysqldump --databases example` which included the `USE` statement. Exporting without the "--databases" option before the database name fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edited to add in comment below:

It looks like it's referring to the example.sql database you're importing into. Have you first granted all privileges to your 'example' user on that example.sql database? Something like

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON example.* TO 'example'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

---

Try putting `` around the database name with the _ in it

```
mysql --user example -p --database `example_database` < example.sql
```

This should allow you to import the whole name

Comment: Exactly the same error. I should mention I've tried quoting and specifying arguments in every way I can think of. `-D \`example_database\``, `--database=example_database`, `--database="example_database"`, `--database="example\_database"`, etc and all have returned the same result.

Comment: Oh! Now I see, have you first granted all privileges to your example.sql database that you're importing into for your example user? `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON example.* TO 'example'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`